# Workaround for removed AutomaticContactMerger class in Kentico 10

Tags: kentico

We've upgraded a Kentico 8.2 website that uses the [AutomaticContactMerger class](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/9_0/api/html/T_CMS_OnlineMarketing_AutomaticContactMerger.htm), up to Kentico 10 which no longer contains that class. The API Changes reference guide [notes the class as being removed](https://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-10/21578) in Kentico 10 but does not suggest alternatives or workarounds to using its merging features.

#### TL;DR Summary

We are looking for a way to port our Contact Management custom merge logic and integrate it into Kentico 10 at the point Kentico runs its default merge logic, just as we did in Kentico 8 as shown in this post (below).

Before hacking into the Kentico 10 API -- whatever that might look like -- I'm looking for recommendations or workarounds to best use the Kentico 10 APIs to achieve the same outcomes: **to register custom mergers that will participate in the Kentico 10 default merge process.**

#### Customization of  Merge Logic

Specifically, our project overrides the Kentico 8 `AutomaticContactMerger` class and provides custom logic as shown in the following C#.NET Kentico 8 code snippet. *(This code has been simplified and sanitised to convey the basic scenario.)*

To understand this code:

- We have a Custom Field on the Kentico Contact class named `EXTERNAL_REFERENCE_VALUE` (string field) that ultimately has its value populated from an external system but not immediately (might be empty), so we key some of our logic around this field value's presence (is it empty or not) and of course the value it contains, in order to customize which Contacts we select to override the default merge logic.
- Source code comments mentioning K8 and K10 mean Kentico verions 8 and 10 respectively.

```cs
/* In Kentico 8 we derive from the CMS.OnlineMarketing.AutomaticContactMerger class 
to provide custom merge logic
based on custom contact fields and rules ... */

public class CUSTOM_ContactMerger : AutomaticContactMerger /* K10 Removed ACM class */ { 

  // ==============================================
  // In K8 OVERRIDE the default Merge with our custom logic. 

  protected override ContactInfo MergeWithinSite(ContactInfo contact, List<ContactInfo> contacts, string siteName) {
    
    if (!base.ContactIsMergedByColumn(FieldNames.Contact.EXTERNAL_REFERENCE_VALUE)) {

      /* Custom logic determines which contacts will be merged */
      var contacts = CUSTOM_GetAllTheContactsIWantToMergeBasedOnCustomRules(..);

      /* Find or make a master contact - more custom rules wrapped up */
      ContactInfo masterContact = CUSTOM_GetMyPreferredMasterContactOrMakeANewOne();

      /* Use Kentico's ContactHelper class to merge all our picked Contacts into the master contact.*/
      ContactHelper.Merge(masterContact, contacts, null, null); // however the .Merge methods are gone in K10 

      return masterContact; // custom selection


  // ==============================================
  // in K8 OVERRIDE the Where Condition for when merge should be ignored (for example).

  protected override string GetWhereCondition(ContactInfo contact) {
    if (CUSTOM_ShouldIgnoreMerge(contact)) {
      return string.Empty;
    }
    return base.GetWhereCondition(contact) ?? string.Empty;
  }
```

A short list of classes and methods we use in the above Kentico 8 code snippet to provide custom merge behaviour, and which no longer exist in the Kentico 10 API are these:

`CMS.OnlineMarketing` namespace -

- `AutomaticContactMerger` class - removed from Kentico 10 including:

  - `.MergeWithinSite(..)` virtual method is overridden
  - `.GetWhereCondition(..)` virtual method is overridden
  - `.ContactIsMergedByColumn(..)` instance method is called
- `ContactHelper` class - exists in Kentico 10 however:

  - `.Merge(..)` static method is used, no longer exists in Kentico 10

#### Registering Custom Merge Logic with Kentico 8

Additionally, we register our own `CustomContactMerger` class with Kentico 8 through a provider in the following standard way. The Kentico 8 method `CMS.OnlineMarketing.ContactInfoProvider.AddAutomaticContactMerger(..)` also no longer exists in Kentico 10, so we will need a way to register custom mergers in Kentico 10. Kentico 8 describes this method as
`/// Registers automatic contact merger that gets ran when method SetContactInfo is called.`

```cs
[assembly: RegisterCustomProvider(typeof(CustomContactInfoProvider))]
public partial class CustomContactInfoProvider : ContactInfoProvider

    static CustomContactInfoProvider()
    {
        var myCustomMerger = new CustomContactMerger(..);

        // Note: we do NOT use Kentico's own email settings, because they will be picked up
        // by Kentico's private method and give email higher priority (than our own merger logic)

        var emailMerger = new CustomContactMerger("ContactEmail", CustomContactMerger.SETTING_MERGE_BY_EMAIL);

        var mergers = new List<CustomContactMerger>()  { merger, emailMerger };
        foreach (var m in mergers)
        {
            // Kentico 8 registration point. Kentico 10 does not have this method call.
            base.AddAutomaticContactMerger(m);
        }
```

---

#### Other Reference Information

Kentico 10 Release Notes about changes to contact management in the core product, as it relates to CMS Desk features:

> By default, the system only merges contacts automatically, which
> caused the following changes:
>
> - It is no longer possible to merge
>   accounts and split the merged accounts in the Contact management
>   application.
> - It is no longer possible to manually merge contacts and
>   split the merged contacts in the Contact management application.
> - It is
>   no longer possible to clone the merged accounts in the Clone account
>   dialog and the merged contacts in the Clone contact dialog.
> - The
>   Automatic merging of contacts setting category with the following
>   settings was removed from Settings -> On-line marketing -> Contact
>   management -> Global data & merging:
>
>   - Merge contacts for identical
>     E-commerce customers; Merge contacts for identical Email campaign
>     subscribers; Merge contacts with identical email addresses and When a
>     visitor has more contacts, use.

~ https://docs.kentico.com/k10/release-notes-kentico-10#Releasenotes-Kentico10-Contactmanagement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a major change to contacts in version 10 of Kentico. I would refer to the release notes here: https://docs.kentico.com/k10/release-notes-kentico-10#Releasenotes-Kentico10-Contactmanagement

Check out the paragraph that starts with

> By default, the system only merges contacts automatically, ...

As far as recommendations go, I would try a test site with no customization at all to understand how contacts and activities work, the new out of the box setup may just work for you.

Alternately, if you share your merge logic we might be able to help more.

Comment: Thank you @mcbeev for the quick feedback. Will review this with the team and provide an edit to the question with additional detail containing the custom merge logic if it's a desired approach after regroup.

Comment: I've updated the question with additional information and more code, and will also submit to Kentico support to get their eyes on the question too.